# Create database at linked server with T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Let's say currently my application connects to a database in server A and there is a function to create an audit database in server B. In this case, is that possible to create the database with T-SQL?

Comment: How are the databases connected?

Comment: Just to make things clear, server B is defined as a linked server at server A? You want to issue a statement from server A to create a database at server B?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the databases should be created when the application is first set up, not on the fly. Normally, you should create the databases by connecting directly to that server. If you want to connect to another server using T-SQL, you may use the OPENROWSET function, but this is not designed for creating databases. To use the OPENROWSET function, you first need to enable the option, like this:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE 
go
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

If you try to create a database using the OPENROWSET function, you may encounter several errors (like *"The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object"* or *"CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction"*).

You can overcome these limitations this way:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'Server=YOURSERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'ROLLBACK; CREATE DATABASE Test; SELECT 1 A')
```

However, this is not a normal usage of the OPENROWSET function, so if anything breaks, you did not learn this from me :-).